# Reduce the size of two numbers but keep their ratio

Tags: divisibility

I have two numbers: `1536` and `2048`, I would like to reduce these numbers to as close as 600 as possible while retaining their ratio. How can I achieve this in mathematics?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *reduce*?

Comment: Keep the current ratio of 1536:2048 but turn the numbers into say 548:600

Comment: Do you want the ratio to be exactly the same, or do only need it close to the original ratio?

Comment: Anyway for this particular example, as the ratio is $3 : 4$ and both $3$ and $4$ divide $600$, you can make either the earlier or latter number exactly $600$: the ratio $1536 : 2048$ is equal to $450 : 600$ and to $600 : 800$. See my answer for a general method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continually divide both numbers by a common factor.

> $2048:1536 = 1024:768 = 512:384 = 256:192 = 128:96 = 64:48 = 32:24 = 16:12 = 8:6 = 4:3$

Notice how I simply continued to divide both numbers by a common factor of $2$. The closest to 600 with these integers was $512:384$.

If you want exactly $600$ for the first term, you could divide both numbers in the original ratio by $\frac{2048}{600}$, and that would give $600:450$.

If it's the other number that you want to be $600$, then you would divide both sides by $\frac{1536}{600}$ instead, which would give you $800:600$.

Comment: Well, another question for the OP is, which number should be close to 600? Does he want 600 to be the bigger number or the smaller number?

Comment: Touche - I fixed my answer, in case that's what OP wanted.

Comment: +1 ;-) the 4:3 ratio at the end was a dead giveaway. The numbers are most likely a resolution and the ratio is of course the standard television aspect ratio.

Comment: You seem to have missed $600 : 450$.

Comment: The numbers are indeed a resolution

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{1536}{2048}=k$

$\dfrac{x}{600}=k$ or $\dfrac{600}{x}=k$

$\dfrac{1536}{2048}=\dfrac{x}{600}$ or $\dfrac{600}{x}=\dfrac{1536}{2048}$.

Solve for $x$, you will still have ratios constant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a systematic recipe (algorithm) for doing what you want, assuming you want the ratio to remain exactly the same. (Otherwise, there are solutions involving continued fractions!)

- First, reduce the given ratio to lowest terms, and call the ratio $p/q$. This involves dividing both the numerator and denominator by their gcd. In other words, if you have a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, in lowest terms it is $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{a\,/\gcd(a,b)}{b\,/\gcd(a,b)}$.
- If $q > 600$, stop. You're already as close as you can get.
- Else, consider the multiples of $q$ closest to $600$. Specifically, you need to consider the two numbers (possibly equal) $l = \lfloor \frac{600}{q} \rfloor$ and $h = \lceil \frac{600}{q} \rfloor$.
- For each of these two, consider the corresponding ratios. That is, consider the ratios $\frac{lp}{lq}$ and $\frac{hp}{hq}$. Pick whichever is "better" according to you.

---

The gcd can be found with the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). For example, Python code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    return abs(a) if b == 0 else gcd(b, a%b)
```

For the given example $1536/2048$: you have $\gcd(1536, 2048) = 512$, so the fraction in lowest terms is $\frac{1536/512}{2048/512} = \frac{3}{4}$. So $q = 4$, and you want $600 / q$, which is $150$. Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $150$ gives the ratio $\frac{150 \times 3}{150 \times 4} = \frac{450}{600}$, so $450 : 600$ is the ratio with denominator closest to $600$.

(Note: if it's the numerator that you want closest to 600, then do the procedure (finding $l$ and $h$) with $p$ in place of $q$. In this case, that gives $600/3 = 200$, so the ratio with numerator closest to $600$ is $600 : 800$, as $\frac{200 \times 3}{200 \times 4} = \frac{600}{800}$. Also, of course, the whole thing works with any number in place of $600$.)